# Java servlet handling Multipart request for a mp4 file

Tags: java, ios, servlets, streaming, mp4

I am trying to implement a servlet which reads an InputStream from a url.
Input stream's content-type is video/mp4.

Now, i want this InputStream containing mp4 video to be served to a iOS device.
I have followed the Bauke Scholtz's [article](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html) which does the similar task, It reads content from a File object. 
I followed this article, and made some changes to implement my scenario.

I am adding some more details to my question.

I have tried to test my scenario by doing minor changes in Bauke Scholtz's code.
My servlet first reads the content from a url by using

```
URLConnection openConnection = url.openConnection();
```

Then i override his copy() function as follows :

```
private static void copy(URLConnection openConnection, OutputStream output,
        long start, long length) throws IOException {
    InputStream input = openConnection.getInputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
    int read;

    if (openConnection.getContentLength() == length) {
        while ((read = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    } else {
        input.skip(start);
        long toRead = length;

        while ((read = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            if ((toRead -= read) > 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, read);
            } else {
                output.write(buffer, 0, (int) toRead + read);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used this copy function instead of the original one.

But i am not able to acheive my goal.
Anybody who has experienced the same, or is acquainted with a solution, please share your thoughts.

Thanks,

Vaibhav Gupta.

P.S. I apologize for the less information provided in my original question. I am very new to stackoverflow, and it will take some time and learning to adapt its culture.

Comment: Need more details about the error.